# Log the time a python script stopped?

Tags: python, time

I want to log (into a `txt` file) the time a Python script stopped. The issue with this is regarding to logic:

If it stopped, it must know when it did - but if it's closed, how can it know? It'd have to be aware of the closing about 1 second ago before it happens. Which led me to the next phase:

A watchdog for the process `"python.exe"`, but that won't work because of the context I want to use it in: I want to know when my computer shuts down via a Python script.

The purpose of this is to log the shutdowns (sleeps) and restarts / wake ups of the computer (Event Viewer doesn't seem to log all of them so I said, hey, why not do it this way?)

Comment: Why don't you just write down the time just before you call the shutdown method from your script? Don't you have all control in your script? I don't get your question to be honest. Are you worried about something killing off your process, or?

Comment: I do have control - but how can the script know when will I press the "sleep" (or long press to shutdown) on my laptop? I guess it would work if I were to always press "shutdown", which I don't. I'm more interested in "sleep" now, because I rarely shutdown my laptop. Makes sense? Also, I have no idea of the implications of "shutdown" so, you might be right!

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For regular terminations, I would suggest using the `atexit` module:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html

You can write the time of termination of your script like this:

```
import datetime
import atexit

def leaving():
   open("my.log", "w").write("I was closed at %s" % datetime.datetime.now())

atexit.register(leaving)
```

Another way would be to use decorators, like this:

```
import atexit

@atexit.register
def leaving():
    import datetime
    open("my.log", "w").write("I was closed at %s" % datetime.datetime.now())
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you, will select as answer.

Comment: decorator usage only works on functions called without arguments.

Comment: Which is ok for this purpose :)

Comment: Yeah, this is the best answer.

Comment: Here's the atexit source, which I'm now inspired to peruse. Thank you Lawrence, I think the asker should probably select this. https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/atexit.py - try `python -matexit` on the command line after reading the source. (first thing registered is last thing run.)

Answer (score 1):

Anything in a finally block is guaranteed to run, so you can do this, so long as you don't catch `SystemExit` or `BaseException` and this gets a shutdown signal or keyboard interrupt:

```
import logging
import time

logger = logging.getlogger(__name__)

def process():
    '''this can be anything, sleep is probably least resource consumptive'''
    while 1:
        time.sleep(5)

def main():
    try:
        process()
    finally: # guaranteed to run, so long as Python gets an error, 
             # shutdown signal or keyboard interrupt.
        logger.info('shutdown at {0}'.format(datetime.datetime.now()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It represents your main process.

Comment: i.e. anything your program does in the meantime while waiting to finish. If you have no work to do, it can just be `while True: pass`

Comment: This works too! So, in the light of fariness, I'll use random.org to select an answer :)

Comment: No, you should select Lawrence, but thanks for the vote of confidence.