# python function that logs time & error when a script failed

Tags: python, exception, logging, error-handling

I'm using python3. I want to print the time a script fails, as well as the corresponding exception in one line. Referring to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55387261/log-when-python-script-failed) & [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27332332/log-the-time-a-python-script-stopped), I tried something like this, but the function didn't execute. Am I doing something wrong here? Would appreciate suggestions.

```py
import atexit
import datetime

#define function to log when script ends due to error/failure
def f_log(date_and_time, error):
    try:
        print("")
    except:
        print('Script ended at date/time: %s with error %s.' % (date_and_time, error))

import atexit
atexit.register(f_log, date_and_time=datetime.datetime.now(), error=Exception)

print "Deliberate error" # Simple example of an error that should be caught & printed along with time when script fails.

# main body of script continues here
#
#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script has multiple problems. (datetime not imported, useless try/except in f_log, ...) The main issue is that a SyntaxError can't be handled. Try this version instead:

```
import atexit
import datetime

#define function to log when script ends due to error/failure
def f_log(date_and_time, error):
    print('Script ended at date/time: %s with error %s.' % (date_and_time, error))


atexit.register(f_log, date_and_time=datetime.datetime.now(), error=Exception)

1/0 # Simple example of an error that should be caught & printed along with time when script fails.
```

Comment: Thank you! I was unaware that a SyntaxError couldn't be handled this way; the error example you used seems to be caught with no problem. I guess I will have to look deeper into which kinds of Exceptions are, well, exceptions. On another note, I hadn't explicitly included the "import" lines in the code snippet here because it isn't related to the problem I had; but after seeing your comment, I've edited my post for clarity so others don't similarly assume that that could be a potential source of error.